# Access button from Layout within GlSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-activity, glsurfaceview

I am working on Android and have being working on OpenGL ES. I have a xml layout as follows (I have took some things out to show only therelative content:

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/myText"/>

<MyGLSurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/mySurface"/>
```

Then in my GlSurfaceView I am trying to access the button that is in the same layout. However this is were I am having a problem.

I have tried the following:

```
View v = (View) getParent();
myTextViewString = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

this

```
myTextViewString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

and this

```
myTextViewString = (TextView) ((RelativeLayout) getParent()).findViewById(R.id.myText);
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to access this button outside of the GLSurfaceView but is in the same activity inside my GLSurfaceView.java.

I do know that it has something to do with not being able to get the parent( I am assuming because it does not extend Activity). I have looked around and I cannot find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Why not pass either the `Context`, or just the button, from the activity to your `GLSurfaceView`? Then you don't have to jump through hoops to get access to it in the view.

Comment: Can you submit an answer on how to accomplish passing it and using i to get id. So I could mark it right. That is an interesting idea i did not think of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clean and straightforward way to do this is to pass the button view to the `GLSurfaceView`. Aside from avoiding navigation through the view hierarchy, this also makes your view code more generic, since it will not have to know the id of a specific button.

In the `onCreate()` method of the activity, after calling `setContentView()`, you could have this:

```
MyGLSurfaceView glView = (MyGLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mySurface);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
glView.setTextView(textView);
```

In `MyGLSurfaceView`:

```
private TextView mTextView;

void setTextView(TextView textView) {
    mTextView = textView;
}
```

Then, in other methods of `MyGLSurfaceView`, you can use `mTextView` anytime you need access to the button.

Comment: Awesome works great, I did not know I could pass references of ui objects. Thanks!